# Short Exact Sequence and Solvable Lie Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathcal{C}$ the set of Lie Algebras that are solvable. I would like to show the following claim:

If $0\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ is a short exact sequence and $\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}\in\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathfrak{g}\in \mathcal{C}.$

I have already proved that $\mathfrak{g}\in \mathcal{C}\iff \mathfrak{h}\in \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}\in \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal. However, I am not too familiar with the idea of a short exact sequence.

Comment: Your questions seems to be what a short exact sequence (of Lie algebras) really is. Start with [vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839230/what-is-a-short-exact-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathfrak h \rightarrow \mathfrak g$ is the usual inclusion map, and $\mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak g/ \mathfrak h$ is the usual projection map, then

$$0 \rightarrow \mathfrak h \rightarrow \mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak g / \mathfrak h \rightarrow 0$$

is an exact sequence.  If you think about what it means for a sequence of lie algebras (or more generally, of vector spaces) to be exact, then this is basically what all short exact sequences look like: the first term is a subspace of the second term, and the third term is the quotient of the second term by the first.